# Simple Cross-Platform Trivia Application

Tags: android, ios, mobile, cross-platform

So I was wondering, which language should I use to build a simple cross-platform trivia application.
With stages you know, and coins.
I have some knowledge in Java and C# and bit of JS.
Hope you guys can help me :)

Comment: Use Java on Android, Objective C or Swift on iOS. Also, these types of questions are too vague and therefore not appropriate for StackOverflow, whose purpose is to answer questions about programming problems.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest using one of the Hybrid mobile application development frameworks. A good Top 10 list is found in [this link](http://noeticforce.com/best-hybrid-mobile-app-ui-frameworks-html5-js-css)

Of course knowing Javascript is essential for most of them. My favourite one is Ionic which is based on AngularJS.